# Closing modal window - returns to the top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple modal popup window. That when closed returns you to the top of the page. I would like it to stay at the same scroll position. Is this possible, im not great with Javascript.

Here is the page: http://pagedev.co.uk/hoppings/product/2-4m-beads

Here is my javascript:

```
$(function(){

var appendthis =  ("<div class='modal-overlay js-modal-close'></div>");

  $('a[data-modal-id]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("body").append(appendthis);
    $(".modal-overlay").fadeTo(1000, 1);
    //$(".js-modalbox").fadeIn(500);
    var modalBox = $(this).attr('data-modal-id');
    $('#'+modalBox).fadeIn($(this).data());
  });  


$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function() {
  $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
  });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".modal-box").css({
    top: ($(window).height() - $(".modal-box").outerHeight()) / 2,
    left: ($(window).width() - $(".modal-box").outerWidth()) / 2
  });
});

$(window).resize();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the close link as you have on the open link:

```
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(".modal-overlay").remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you use `href='#'`

```
<a class="js-open-modal" href="#" data-modal-id="12" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'PDF Download', 'Link Click', 'Q-Line 2.4m D Mould');"><div class="product-hover"></div></a>
```

you can prevent that in javascript

```
$(".js-modal-close, .modal-overlay").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".modal-box, .modal-overlay").fadeOut(500, function() {
       $(".modal-overlay").remove();
   });
}
```